# SVG path to x,y coordinates using D3

Tags: d3.js, svg, path

Is there a way I can feed d3 a svg path, for example:

```
M22.8,149.7c46.6-3.9,91.3-19.7,136.3-31.6c46.4-12.3,93.3-22.9,140.5-31.8c26.8-5.1,53.7-9.6,80.6-13.7 c3.2-0.5,1.8-5.3-1.3-4.8c-47.2,7-94.1,15.7-140.7,26c-46.1,10.2-91.6,22.5-137.1,35.1c-25.7,7.1-51.7,13.5-78.3,15.8 C19.6,145,19.6,150,22.8,149.7L22.8,149.7z
```

and have it return the x, y coordinates so I can recreate using just those?

Comment: x, y coordinates of its beginning and end point?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384052/convert-svg-path-d-attribute-to-a-array-of-points