# Animate footprints along a path

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I got inspiration from this [pen](https://codepen.io/bhargavgandhi/pen/mRWjqB) where there are animated footprints. My question is how could I combine it with a given trajectory so that the footprints will just follow the path? My path would be something like:

```
<svg id="svg" width="800" height="800">
    <path id="path" d="M130 20 L230 80 L200 100 L170 200"/>
    <image id="footprint" xlink:href="http://icons.veryicon.com/png/System/Icons8%20Metro%20Style/Tracks%20Footprints%20Left%20shoe.png" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="50px"/>
</svg>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: maybe this might help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tae96ze3xwY 
since they animate text on a scroll on a path.

Comment: I would love to keep the footstep motion like that in the pen. I know I can use animateMotion to move the footprint around, but the motion shouldn't be continous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose i suggest you to use **[GREENSOCK](https://greensock.com/)**, light weight easy to use and full of animation what ever you need IN you scenario

May be this will help you

```
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwr6mqx2g/image/upload/v1489592258/leftfoot_hjajqj.svg" id="leftfoot">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dwr6mqx2g/image/upload/v1489592258/rightfoot_fthak3.svg" id="rightfoot">
```

Some JS

```
var $rightfoot = $("#rightfoot"),
    $leftfoot = $("#leftfoot");

var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1})



  var ease = SteppedEase.config(5);

tl

  .to($rightfoot, 0.25, {autoAlpha:1,},1)
  .to($leftfoot, 0.25, {autoAlpha:1,},1)
  .to($leftfoot, 3, 

  {bezier:{ curviness: 1, values:[{x:0, y:0},{x:52, y:-25}, {x:97, y:-39}, {x:136, y:-54}, {x:172, y:-83}, {x:197, y:-117},{x:200, y:-163,}],
  autoRotate:90}, ease:ease},1)

  .to($rightfoot, 3, 
  {bezier:{ curviness: 1, values:[{x:0, y:0}, {x:44, y:-13}, {x:97, y:-28,}, {x:134, y:-49,}, {x:166, y:-83,}, {x:182, y:-126,}, {x:176, y:-163,}],
  autoRotate:100}, ease:ease},1.25)
```

Referene

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Spira/pen/qrpjZv)

Credits **Jenna**

Comment: Thank you very much for these! Do you know how my path data can be combined in this scenario? The trajectory needs to follow <path id="path" d="M130 20 L230 80 L200 100 L170 200"/> where the path data is given in d. In your answer, it seems that this is arbitrarily given in bezier and .to

Comment: Not exactly @saladham. may be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384052/convert-svg-path-d-attribute-to-a-array-of-points